# Can individual classes from CodeIgniter be integrated into other frameworks / projects?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Can individual classes from CodeIgniter be integrated into other frameworks / projects without using the underlying framework to build the application?

I believe this can be achieved in Zend if I only wanted to use specific classes (such as Zend_DB, Zend_Validate, etc…) by linking to just that component without needing to use the underlying framework for building the application.  Can someone please confirm this?  In addition, what other frameworks (e.g., Symphony, CakePHP) have this ability, specifically CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the class definitions and see what they depend on. Likely they are tightly coupled to the rest of the framework.

ZF was defined from the beginning as a collection of components, or tools, which is why stealing individual classes is so easy - it was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

CI is meant to be extremely [loosely coupled](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/goals.html), so perhaps OP will have some luck. I don't have any examples however